# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas

I have a component. It is loaded into another component. I want to click the first component, and initiate an action on my canvas in the second component. I get however, 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined', which i assume is because it is outside the components ts file.

How can i integrate this together?

1. Component A is nested in Component B.
2. Component A on click, calls an action on the canvas that is in component B.
3. Canvas throws an Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.

Code for component A on click i want to initiate the canvas in component B:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'MouseComponent',
  templateUrl: './mouse.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mouse.scss']
})

export class MouseComponent {

@ViewChild('canvas_element') canvas_element: ElementRef;

clickie(){

  let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canvas_element.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = mouseX + ' | ' + mouseY;
  });

  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    console.log('Mouse Click At:', mouseX + ' | ' + mouseY);
  });

}
}
```

Component B html (has nothing in the TS file other than standard):

```
<div container-fluid>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3 sidebar-container'>
        <div class='col-md-2 action-bar'>
          <MouseComponent></MouseComponent>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-12 top-bar'></div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-md-9 canvas-container' style="text-align:center;">
       <canvas #canvas_element class='write-canvas'></canvas>
       <p>Status:</p>
       <p id='status'></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am by no means an angular 2 expert, but surely it cannot be this hard to trigger a canvas action on click?

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: Code has been updated.